# Library dirac3-le progress update after timeshift

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing a simple musicplayer with the possibility to change the speed of the song. As a time-shift library I'm using dirac3-le. For some reason currentTime() returns only 0. So I reversed the function bach to version 1.0. (seems like mFramePositionInInputFile is 0).

```
-(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //return (NSTimeInterval)mFramePositionInInputFile / mSampleRate;

    // this was the code used in version 1.0:
    return (NSTimeInterval)mTotalFramesPlayed / mSampleRate;
}
```

Having done this I can calculate the total Time of the Song and the current Time in Minutes like this:

```
    int totalMinutes = (int)self.player.fileDuration/60;
    int totalSeconds =(int)self.player.fileDuration % 60;
    self.songTotalTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02i", totalMinutes, totalSeconds];

    int currentMinutes = (int)self.player.currentTime/60;
    int currentSeconds = (int)self.player.currentTime % 60;
    self.songCurrentTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02i", currentMinutes, currentSeconds];
```

But when I change the speed of the song, the time is returned in with the old speed. So by twice the speed the time is only at 50%. Same with the progressview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-currentTime uses the ProcessingBeganCallback() which is only supported in the commercial version of Dirac."

So basically I have to run my own implementation.